# PHP rtrim() or similar function for removing X amount of characters from string

Tags: php

This should be pretty basic. I've searched all over the best matching function (as far as I can see from PHP Manual is rtrim)

I've got a string. I want to remove X-amount of characters from, specifically the first 4 characters from the string.

EXAMPLE:

> Fri, Dec 1, 2017
>
> Sat, Dec 2, 2017
>
> Sat, Dec 2, 2017

I would like to remove the first 4 characters from the left including white space after comma in order for me to have a date I can work with without day of week.

Now according to manual and W3Schools `rtrim()` enables you to do the above. However as I understand it, [you have to put in the characters / text you want to be trimmed from string.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

My problem is the days of the week will alternate from MON - SUN thus I can not put specific characters.

**I'm trying to trim with index numbers starting from left 0-4**

So at the end:

> Fri, Dec 1, 2017

Should read

> Dec 1, 2017

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try;

```
substr("Fri, Dec 1, 2017", 5);
```